# 16" Pop-up Spray Heads

Tags: irrigation

Are 16 " high pop-up spray heads available? I have a 12" high pop-up spray head positioned 3' from a rose bush. It sprays forefully into the small rose bush (15" - 18" high). I prefer not to move the head, the spray covers the rest of the plants in the mulched bed. What I would like to do is leave the head in that location and simply change the 12" pop-up spray head to a 16" (or higher if available) thereby raising the spray height so it doesn't spray forcefully into the small rose bush.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a 16” pop-up that I have run across in the irrigation world.  Or perhaps I should say, none of the major US manufacturers make such a beast.  Rainbird makes a 6” extension (part # 1800-ext) that can be screwed onto the pop-up below the nozzle.  These stick up above the ground are are quiet fragile because of the fine threads.  The flip side is you can screw several together and they even work on Toro heads.  They probably fit most of the the other companies as well, but I mostly have experience with Toro and Rainbird.

You could also swap ALL the heads in that zone to a stream spray. I prefer the Hunter MP stream spray to the Rainbird but there's really no basis behind it.  They work better in larger areas so if the beds are small I'd go with@stormy's suggestions.  The nice thing about stream sprays is they are designed to shoot thought the plant.

Answer (score 0):

I would shorten the head instead of raising it.  Please send a bit more information on your head/nozzle or look up Rain Bird.  These guys I trusted.

Plants like to be washed off by free water.  I can understand getting the roses wet is not good for roses and would hold too much water for too long and in the sun could decimate flowers.  Water ONLY in the morning never at night. If you are watering a little every day we need to talk.

If you lowered your popup, the water would spray the branches down lower and be able to assure water to that shrub.  Higher would mean that shrub, rose would be missed...not mist, grins...and all the other shrubs would get watered missing your rose? the spray would have more chance to evaporate, less water to the soil.

The sprays should over lap, that was how they were designed.  Have you tried turning off that head?  If you did, the pressure of the other heads will rise a bit and if the coverage is good chances are good that your rose is getting watered that is what I would do.

I've never tried making a head into a drip.  Didn't have this option back in the day...think about making that head into a drip...even better.  I want to see what happens to the pressure of the other heads. Check out the link I am sending.  I would also call Rain Bird and talk directly with them.  Lots of better designs to be had today that I don't know about.

Segway:

If you are watering correctly you should only be using 1" of water on your landscape per week.  This takes a bit of time to train your plants but saves mucho bucks on your water bill and makes your plants drought proof, you lawn drought proof. Most people water every day and that is a waste and unhealthy for your plants.  If you haven't done the kitty cat can test or tuna fish can test let us know and we can direct you.

I know this wasn't part of your question, but if you are worried about a rose bush (yay) I would imagine you might care about your water bill.  And I want to find out how well this 'drip' head works!

[from riser to drip connection Rain Bird](http://store.rainbird.com/drip-low-volume/rckit-1pk-1800-spray-head-drip-riser-connection-kit.html)

Comment: Shortening the height of the pop-up will mean nearly all of the spray will impact the rose bush leaving little to no spray left for the rest of the plants in the mulch bed.

Comment: Going to a 16" or higher pop-up spray head gets me spray above the rose bush, giving me coverage of not only the rose bush but all the other plants in the mulch bed. Coverage from the spray head is relatively uniform from the head out to the limits of the coverage resulting in coverage from the rose bush out to the rest of the plants in the mulch bed. I repeat, are 16" or higher pop-up spray heads available?

Comment: I asked for a picture at the very least.  My ideas were based on...what little I could discern.  Most heads, as I tried to communicate are placed to cover ie)15' diameters with 1/3 overlap.  By turning this one head off, for instance, if that would cause a major hole in the watering I would be concerned about the design of your system.  One irrigation head too high will cause an artificial hole right below it depending on soil and timer.  My advice to you is not that of a retail sales clerk.  I tried to give you a far bigger picture.  Call Rain Bird, I am sure there are ways to 'stack' heads.

Comment: Yes, there are 16" risers.  Standardized parts to make what ever height you want or need.  Home Depot; up to 24"!  Adapters and reducers and pvc plumbing stuff with which you can do what ever you think best.